# What's New in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9

I tried to learn but not getting clear about the same. So anyone please send me the valuable links or points for the Angular 9  new features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added Angular 9 Features -

1. Added undecorated classes migration schematic in the core.
2. The formControlName also accepts a number in the form
3. Now allow selector-less directives as base classes in View Engine in the compiler.
4. Added support selector-less directive as base classes in Ivy and also make the Ivy compiler the default for ngc.
5. Convert all ngtsc diagnostics to ts.Diagnostics
6. bazel: support ts_library targets as entry-points for ng_package.
7. core: add dynamic queries schematic.
8. core: Mark TestBed.get as deprecated.
9. ivy: expose window.ng.getDebugNode helper and also support ng-add in localize package.
10. ivy: i18n – add syntax support for $localize metadata block.
11. ivy: i18n – reorganize entry-points for better reuse.
12. language-service: enable logging on TypeScriptHost.
13. language-service: provide diagnostic for invalid templateUrls.
14. language-service: provide diagnostics for invalid styleUrls.

Explore in Great detail [What's New in Angular 9? Angular 9 New Features](https://www.code-sample.com/2019/08/whats-new-in-angular-9-angular-9-new.html)

Comment: Before you post an answer make you the aren't posted already. I posted it before you.

Comment: ok, will keep in mind for the future.

Comment: great answer, thank for quick you response.

Answer (score 3):

**Top 5 New Features of Angular 9 -**

-Added undecorated classes migration schematic in the core.

-The formControlName also accepts a number in the form

-Now allow selector-less directives as base classes in View Engine in the compiler.

-Added support selector-less directive as base classes in Ivy and also make the Ivy compiler the default for ngc.

-Convert all ngtsc diagnostics to ts.Diagnostics

https://www.quora.com/Whats-new-in-angular-9

**Following fixes in Ivy:**

[downsides of using Ivy in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460828/downsides-of-using-ivy-in-angular/58468851#58468851)

**To learn more about other feature and breaking changes:**

https://jaxenter.com/angular-v9-thread-159065.html

Answer (score 0):

The Ivy Compiler is the main feature of this release. Clearly the most insteresting change!

Comment: You can already use Ivy, but it comes with some bug fixes on Angular 9 https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: I know that, I should add 'The ivy Compiler as main compiler'